# Creating SQL query with line breaks in a single string

Tags: c#, sql, ssms

In the SQL Server Management Studio I create a new query and then I run the following code:

```
select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction()
union
select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction()
```

Then I try to do the same thing from my C# program. However I am having trouble to translate the above to one Query string. I have tried the following, but without any success:

```
string QueryString = @"select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction() /r/n union /r/n select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction()"
```

and

```
string QueryString = @"select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction(); union; select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction();"
```

and

```
string QueryString = @"select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction(); union select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction();"
```

I am very new to SQL so if anyone could help me with the correct syntax I would be very happy! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you have to have a break line when you make union query.

Comment: "without any success": please state what happens. A runtime error message?

Comment: I did not recieve any error messages. However I only recieved the data from the first select and the rest was just ignored

Comment: Forget about the breakline. Do not include /r/n in your string.

Comment: .. and don't put in ";"s.  What's inside the quotes should be what SQL expects, don't try to turn it into C#-like statements.

Comment: So, you tried what @Jonesy suggests?

Comment: BTW, what do you get if you do "union all", instead of "union"?  Not suggesting it as your answer, but maybe will shed some light on what is happening..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i dont think you need to worry about the newline

```
@"select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction() union select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction()"
```

Comment: This solution was the most obvious one from the beginning, but it didn't work in the SSMS, so I discarded it without testing it in my own program first. Silly me. Anyways, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7):

If you're using a verbatim string (i.e. defined with the @ sign before the opening quotes) then you can just press the return key in the middle of the definition, for example:

```
string QueryString = @"select dbName.dbo.ScalarFunction()
union
select dbName2.dbo.ScalarFunction()";
```

Answer (score 4):

The carriage return should be `\r\n` and not `/r/n`

You can also use `Environment.NewLine`

Anyway, as stated in other answers, you should not worry about line breaks in SQL

Comment: Good job, spotting that mistake.

Comment: Fair enough. Still not the required result... :/